# AngularJS how do I update GUI when Promise returns

Tags: angularjs

My view is bound to a collection of objects which renders perfectly.  One of the properties is async, which when it returns does not update that value in the GUI.  To kick of the async work I map each property that is to be displayed, zero in on the async property, and do something like this:

```
function getDetails(thing) {
    console.log("---->" + thing.id);
    thingService
        .getDetailsAsync(thing.id, true)
        .then(function Success(result) {
            thing.details = result.details;                                   
        }, function Error(reason) {
            thing.details = [];             
        });
}
```

The thing is a part one object of the binding of $scope.details which the GUI uses.

```
$scope.meeting.map(thing=>{
    getDatails(thing);
});
```

The async updates never show but all of the other fields do show in the GUI.  Shouldn't the GUI autoupdate when each promise is done?  Do I need to do a $scope.Apply() [which didn't work either] or do I need to "pluck" out each thing from $scope.meeting and reset to the new resolved promise object?

I'm confused, please help.

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: `map` should only be used if you're going to be saving the result; it's meant to take the elements of one array and process them into another array of the same length. You should be using `forEach()` or a `for` loop.

Comment: Is it because your function call is `getDatails()` and your function is `getDetails()`?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final answer was completely different.  It turned out another component was already issuing the async queries I needed.  I simply put an emitter there and waited for the answers to come in...  (sounds like RXjs).

But to get the updated records to show, I had to find the record in the array, update it, and then update the array record.  Like this:

```
var found = _.find(details, { id:id }
if(found){ found.notes = emittedData;}
found = found; <--This fired of the re-render with new data.
```

Being new to the digest cycle, I had thought just setting the property was enough to detect a change and re-render.

Please comment.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have shared, all I am getting is that,
you are passing the "$scope object" to the `getDetails()` function as an argument which basically creates a new local object "thing" to the `getDetails` function in JS and updates this local object rather than the $scope object.

So, you should go with [`(your $scope object).details = result.details`] in place of [`thing.details = result.details`].